# Letter Speech Recognition using octave

Tags: octave, speech-recognition, fft, speech-to-text, audio-processing

I am trying to recognise all the letters of the alphabet from audio files.
The audio files (26) are my recordings of speaking the alphabet.
So I am trying to implement a speech to text program, where the input is my voice speaking a letter which I am trying to predict what is it.

I guess I will have to do some kind of convertion of the sound like fft, spectrograms ex. Collect some info of the sound like zero-cross-rate, max frequency etc..
And then try to find the most similar one with something like euclidean distance.

I am trying doing this only using octave.
I don't want the full code, I just want to know where to start. How would you do it?

Comment: Performing classification over the fourier on specific octave bands as your input features should probably work. For the classification you could either try a simple neural network, or some form of clustering. (PS. this question doesn't sound like it has much to do with Octave ... unless I'm missing the point?)

Comment: I mention that I can't use nothing more than octave, because I have to do it on vanilla octave.

Comment: What do you mean specific octave bands?

Comment: "Octave bands": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octave_band (sorry for the confusion, octave bands have nothing to do with "Gnu Octave"; it's just a conventional way to subdivide the frequency spectrum).

Comment: Yeah I knew what you where talking about. How would I pick the right frequency bands, how can I know which ones are the important ones? So then I can do the right feauture extraction and feed the neural network/ml algorithms. Could I use something else except classification?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "something else"; you're trying to classify an input into one of 26 letter categories. That's classification by definition. Picking the "right" frequency bands is not a single question. E.g. you could train a neural network on all available ones, and then perform a sensitivity analysis of some kind to see which bands carry the most classification weight. Or you could try a regularizer which promotes sparsity in the parameters, like the l1-norm. Or you could perform some form of dimensionality reduction first, etc. The world's your oyster, really.